# Drupal have error Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required

Tags: drupal

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/webmaster/main/sites/all/modules/advanced_forum/includes/views/advanced_forum_handler_field_node_topic_iconinc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/webmaster/main/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 3186
```

I update module after that have error.

Answer (score 0):

First, check integrity of your module.

Second, if your module is okay use registry_rebuild. Place it on your sites/all/modules folder and call (registry_rebuild.php).

Example with your browser :  http://yourdomain.local/sites/all/modules/registry_rebuild/registry_rebuild.php